# Invalid text, ntext, or image pointer value

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, binary, webforms

I am trying to upload a file to my database (by reading the binary file contents into my stored procedure).  I am passing the input stream to my method like so:

```
LoadFile(gAttachmentContentID, file.InputStream, trn);

public static void LoadFile2(Guid gAttachmentContentID, Stream stm, IDbTransaction trn)
{
    stm.Position = 0;
    byte[] binFILE_POINTER = new byte[32];

    // Now read s into a byte buffer. 
    byte[] bytes = new byte[stm.Length];
    int numBytesToRead = (int)stm.Length;
    int numBytesRead = 0;
    while (numBytesToRead > 0)
    {
        // Read may return anything from 0 to 10. 
        int n = stm.Read(bytes, numBytesRead, 10);
        // The end of the file is reached. 
        if (n == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        numBytesRead += n;
        numBytesToRead -= n;
    }
    stm.Close();
    SqlProcs.spATTACHMENTS_CONTENT_WriteOffset(gAttachmentContentID, binFILE_POINTER, 0, bytes, trn);
    // numBytesToRead should be 0 now, and numBytesRead should 
    // equal 100.
    Console.WriteLine("number of bytes read: {0:d}", numBytesRead);
}
```

With this procedure:

```
public static void spATTACHMENTS_CONTENT_WriteOffset(Guid gID, byte[] binFILE_POINTER, Int32 nFILE_OFFSET, byte[] byBYTES, IDbTransaction trn)
{
    IDbConnection con = trn.Connection;
    using ( IDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand() )
    {
        cmd.Transaction = trn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        if ( Sql.IsOracle(cmd) )
            cmd.CommandText = "spATTACHMENTS_CONTENT_WriteOff";
        else
            cmd.CommandText = "spATTACHMENTS_CONTENT_WriteOffset";
        IDbDataParameter parID               = Sql.AddParameter(cmd, "@ID"              , gID                );
        IDbDataParameter parFILE_POINTER     = Sql.AddParameter(cmd, "@FILE_POINTER"    , binFILE_POINTER    );
        IDbDataParameter parMODIFIED_USER_ID = Sql.AddParameter(cmd, "@MODIFIED_USER_ID",  Security.USER_ID  );
        IDbDataParameter parFILE_OFFSET      = Sql.AddParameter(cmd, "@FILE_OFFSET"     , nFILE_OFFSET       );
        IDbDataParameter parBYTES            = Sql.AddParameter(cmd, "@BYTES"           , byBYTES            );
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> *Invalid text, ntext, or image pointer value 0x00000000000000000000000000000000.*

The error occurs on the line `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` of my stored procedure method.

Stored procedure:

```
Create Procedure dbo.spATTACHMENTS_CONTENT_WriteOffset
    ( @ID                   uniqueidentifier
    , @FILE_POINTER         binary(16)
    , @MODIFIED_USER_ID     uniqueidentifier
    , @FILE_OFFSET          int
    , @BYTES                image
    )
with encryption
as
  begin
    set nocount on

    -- 10/22/2005 Paul.  @ID is used in Oracle and MySQL. 
-- #if SQL_Server /*
    updatetext ATTACHMENTS_CONTENT.ATTACHMENT
               @FILE_POINTER
               @FILE_OFFSET
               null -- 0 deletes no data, null deletes all data from insertion point. 
               @BYTES;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can we see the code for the stored proc?

Comment: Sure you can, it has been updated.

Comment: Why are you only updating *part* of the field using updatetext? Why not just replace it?

Comment: Good question.  This was a procedure from the previous developer.  If you have an alternate suggestion, please advise.  However, I don't think this is what's causing the error.

Comment: I think it is. The error looks like something that might result from invalid pointer and/or offset values. Are you uploading a single file per row? What's the datatype for the file field?

Comment: I am not married to this concept; feel free to provide a new method if you think it would work better.  I am just trying to get these contents into the DB, one way or another.  The field type is `image`.

Comment: [*`ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are uploading only a single file per row it would be much easier to just use a normal UPDATE instead of fiddling around with pointers and offsets unnecessarily. The command can be as simple as this:

```
UPDATE ATTACHMENTS_CONTENT SET ATTACHMENT = @BYTES Where ID=@ID
```

I wasn't sure what your ID field was, so I just wrote ID but I'm sure you can substitute it with the correct one.

Comment: Thanks, I went with a variation of your answer.

Comment: @user1477388 - Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

Well you haven't filled in binFILE_POINTER[], so it will be full of zeroes.

And I'm guessing that's where:

```
*Invalid text, ntext, or image pointer value 0x00000000000000000000000000000000.*
```

is coming from...

Comment: How do you recommend I fill in `binFILE_POINTER[]`?